# How to use the Columns of dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I have a result set of `dataset` like below

[![Dataset][1]][1]

Now I want to add the `IF` condition for checking like below

```
if(dataset rows(Usermail) == 10000){then go ahead}
```

this is my code.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("GET_INWARD_REMINDER_REPORT", conn);
            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;
            da.Fill(ds);

            if(DataSet rowchecking)
            {

            }
        }
```

> So my issue, how to check and compare dataset columns.

Comment: You need to access a field in a row, get its value and not the column.

Comment: @Alex: That only i want to know, how to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
int First = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["columnName1"].ToString());
string Second = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["columnName2"].ToString();
```

So for your case it can be like:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    if(dr["UserEmail"].ToString() == "10000")
    {
      //do something;
    }         
}
```

Comment: but it goes only one mail, can we loop it ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `foreach` to loop the rows and use `DataRow.Field` to get the email:

```
foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    if(row.Field<string>("UserEmail") == "10000")
        continue;  // or revert it and do something if UserEmail != "1000"
}
```

Comment: getting error as **system.data.dataset' does not contain a definition for 'tables'** at `Table`

Comment: @NK: fixed it, its `Tables` not `Table`

Comment: yes, also at line `row.Field<string>("UserEmail"))` I am getting error as **cannot implicitly convert string to bool

Comment: @NK: really sure that you have used the code above? It's `if(row.Field<string>("UserEmail") == "10000")...`

Comment: sorry, i didn't changed that. Updated with your latest one..Now no error. Cheking

Comment: Its not moving after `if (row.Field<string>("UserEmail") == "10000")` Also I am using windows form. will the code effect that ?

Comment: @NK: what means "it's not moving after..."?

Comment: I mean, the debugger does not moves after that line. and a window pop up opens which means there is something wrong

Comment: Sorry, but you are very cryptic. What popup opens with what message, what is wrong, do you get an errror? If you already use the debugger, what value is stored in `row.Field<string>("UserEmail")`? If its `"10000"` this row is skipped, that's what the `continue` statement does. Otherwise the code after the `continue` within the loop will be processed.

Answer (score 0):

After Fill dataset.

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    if(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UserEmail"].ToString() == "10000")
    {
     //do something;
    }
  }
}
```